# Physically Meaningful Solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics

> I have this in my notes where:
>   $$\Phi(x) = \left\{
>                 \begin{array}{ll}
>                   \Phi_I(x) = Ae^{k^{\prime}x} + Be^{-k^{\prime}x} &\text{if }x<0\\
>                   \Phi_{II}(x) = C\sin(kx + \theta) &\text{if }0\le x\le a\\
>                   \Phi_{III}(x) = De^{k^{\prime}x} + Ee^{-k^{\prime}x} &\text{if } x>0
>                 \end{array}
>               \right.$$
>   and it says that there is only a physically meaningful solution when $B=0$ and $D=0$.

Can someone explain why this is please? I'm just confused by it. I first think about complex numbers but there are none in the solution so what else could it be?

Comment: What is $D$ here?

Comment: Perhaps $\Phi_{III}$ should have constants $D$ and $E$.  Maybe even condition $x>a$ and not $x>0$.

Comment: My mistake people. I have edited it now

Answer (score 3):

First, a typo in your question:  I assume the wavefunction $\Phi_{III}(x)$ should be $De^{k^{\prime}x} + Ee^{-k^{\prime}x}$ in the region $x > a$, not $Ae^{k^{\prime}x} + Be^{-k^{\prime}x}$ in the region $x > 0$ as you've written.

States in quantum physics are only physically meaningful if they have a finite norm.  In the case of a wavefunction in 1-D, this translates to the condition
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Phi(x)|^2 \, dx < \infty.
$$
But if $D \neq 0$, the wavefunction will be approximately equal to $D e^{kx}$ as $x \to \infty$, and the integral will diverge as we take the bounds of integration to infinity.  A similar thing will happen as $x \to -\infty$ if we have $B \neq 0$.  Thus, we must have $B = D = 0$ for the wavefunction to have finite norm.

Comment: Ahh yes you are quite right my mistake. So what you're saying is that if $B$ and $D$ don't equal zero then the integral will tend to infinity?

Comment: @Michael:  That's precisely it.

Comment: oh wonderful! Thank you very much this has made things much more clear @Michael